# How to access html control value in code behind without using runat server?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, c#-4.0

Here I have using javascript for adding html control(Input). here I am not able to apply asp.net control because it come dynamically from java script  I just want to use input value in my coed behind page which is generated by javascript dynamically.

Is there any way to get value from HTML control in asp.net.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By using Request.Form["id"]` on Button_Click, you will get the value of html control

`string id = Request.Form["id"]`

Comment: Yes it worked:Use "<input type="text" id="txt" name="txt" />" in aspx file and "Response.Write(Request.Form["txt"])" on btn_Click. Note it will access value through "name" of the html control not id.

Comment: I had checked at my end, it will not work. can you test at your end ?

Comment: Ya i just checked at my end and it worked, paste your code please

Answer (score 3):

You can access the form control **without** having `runat="server"` you need to do following

- The form method should be of type POST.
- The tag should have an attribute called NAME. Because it is used as key in form[].
- Html control should be access in code behind.

*Html*

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" >   
    <input type="text" name="txtName" value="hidden text" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />   
</form>
```

*C# Code:*

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string s = Page.Request.Form["txtName"];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ajax post to post your data from the client to the server code . You need to write a web method in asp.net page and user ajax post .
here is an example

http://encosia.com/2008/05/29/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

get a text area.

In Head use a java script function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function getvalue(temp) {


            var imgcontrol = document.getElementById(temp);
            alert(imgcontrol.value);

        }
</script>
```

If you want to use in code behind so just take a value in hidden field & access it.
in alert you will get value.I hope it help you.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["foo"]
//Gets the input field with name foo
HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["foo"]
//Gets the dynamically added input type='file'
```